# Accessing ng-init variable with filter

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to init a filtered list with angularjs, I don't know how to access to ng-init variables...

**Edit #1 :**

```js
app.controller("AgreementsController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.agreements = [];    
    $http.get('/api/agreement').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.agreements = data.agreements;
    $scope.filteredAgreements = $filter('filter')($scope.agreements,
                                          {number: $scope.search});
});
```

```html
<tbody ng-init="filteredAgreements = (agreements | filter:{number:search})">
  <tr ng-repeat="agreement in agreements | filter:{number:search} | limitTo:5">
    <td>{{agreement.number}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
{{filteredAgreements.length}} <!-- 291 even if I put "65" into the search -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by _ng-init variables_? And where is `AgreementsController` to be found in the DOM in relation to the HTML you posted?

Comment: The variables in `ng-init`... My controller well in the dom but not in the post ;)

Comment: That's tautology. There are no variables in `ngInit`. `ngInit` evaluates an expression in the current scope. If that's the same scope the controller operates on then the controller can access it via the scope.

Comment: Ok so how to access to `filteredAgreements` ?

Comment: Like you did. But `agreements` is empty when `ngInit` is run. Therefore `filteredAgreements` is empty, too. One has to wonder why you use `ngInit` anyway.

Comment: I use `ngInit` because I want to get all filtered agreements without limit, is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 1):

You get `agreements` via AJAX, that means at the time the `ngInit` directive runs they are empty and therefore `filteredAgreements` will be empty, too. You have to wait until the AJAX call returns.

To use an angular filter in JavaScript you need the `$filter` service. You call it with the name of the filter to get the filter, and then call that function with the data to be filtered (in your case `agreements`) and the desired arguments.

```
app.controller("AgreementsController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $scope.agreements = [];    
  $http.get('/api/agreement').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.agreements = data.agreements;
    $scope.filteredAgreements = $filter('filter')($scope.agreements,
                                              {number: $scope.search});
});
```

References:

- [$filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/service/$filter)
- [The "filter" filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: @tonymx227 And why is it `undefined` ? I only have the information you give us.

Comment: See edit ;) The length of `filteredAgreements` is 291 even if I put something into the input form...